# Is it true that in a discrete valuation ring the maximal length of a strictly containing chain of prime ideals is one?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring (DVR). I want to understand what the maximal length of a strictly increasing chain of prime ideals in a DVR is. So I want to compute the Krull dimension of $R$.

I know that the Samuel function of $R$ is $$\chi(n)=n+1$$But then we had a theorem telling that the Samuel function is eventually polynomial so there exists an $N\in \Bbb{N}$ and $f\in \Bbb{Q}[X]$ such that $\chi(n)=f(n)$ for all $n\geq N$. Then we also could show that $\deg(f)=\dim(R)$ where $\dim(R)$ defines the Krull dimension. In my opinion this does mean that the Krull dimension is $1$ right? So I know that the maximal length of a strictly increasing chain of prime ideals is $1$ is this correct?

But using this argumentation I can't say anything about how many prime ideals we $R$ has right?

Comment: This can (and should) be done very explicitly. A discrete valuation ring has a uniformizing element $\pi\in R$ and every ideal of $R$ is either $(0)$ or has the form $(\pi^n)$ for some $n\ge0$. The only prime ideals among these are $(0)$ and $(\pi)$.

Comment: @Thorgott why do I know that every ideal is of the form $(0)$ or $(\pi^n)$. Because we only had that the maximal ideal is $(\pi)$

Comment: This combines the two facts that every element of $R\setminus\{0\}$ has the form $u\pi^n$ for some $u\in R^{\times}$ and $n\ge0$ and that $R$ is a PID.

Comment: @Thorgott ah I See thanks a lot!